# Trying to create an arc in scikit-image comes out wrong

Tags: python-3.x, math, scikit-image

I am trying to create an arc based on the following information:

- radius
- x1,y1 and x2,y2 points on the circumference of a circle.

xy co-ordinates are defined as:

```
x = radius * cos(angle) + center_x
y = radius * sin(angle) + center_y
```

I've tried using `line`, `line_aa` and `bezier`. The latter I got the midway angle of x1,y1 to x2,y2. But the results not what I would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is I am using `angle` but `cos()` and `sin()` use radians. This can be fixed with:

```
r = radians(angle)
x = radius * cos(r) + center_x
y = radius * sin(r) + center_y
```